# Ruby on Rails: How to display everything associated with user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I have some associations that is connected to the user

User model

```
has_many :lists
has_many :ideas
```

How do I display the lists and ideas in the user's page?

In my users controller, show method

```
  def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user } 
    end  
  end
```

In my show.html.erb

I can only display user name, i.e.:

```
<%= @user.username %>
```

I'm trying to see what I need to put in the show action so I can do something like

`@user.lists.name`, or `@user.ideas.name`

I'm new to rails still and I'm trying to understand how to link everything together with user?

Hopefully this is enough information?

Thanks

Comment: you could also use `def show
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:id])` in your controller. This is how i display the data of the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those associations returns collections, an array of many objects.  So you must iterate though all the association records.

```
<p>Name: <%= @user.username %></p>

<p>Ideas:</p>
<ul>
  <% @user.ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <li><%= idea.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<p>Lists:</p>
<ul>
  <% @user.lists.each do |list| %>
    <li><%= list.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Which might render something like:

```
<p>Name: Andrew</p>

<p>Ideas:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Light Bulb</li>
  <li>Cotton Gin</li>
  <li>Smokeless Ashtray</li>
</ul>

<p>Lists:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Chores</li>
  <li>Shopping</li>
  <li>Wishlist</li>
</ul>
```